# Is there a way to save all opened tabs to clipboard for pasting?

Tags: windows, browser, bookmarks, microsoft-edge, browser-tabs

Is there a way in Microsoft Edge Browser to save all my opened tabs to my clipboard with the link to the sites and their titles that I can copy and paste anywhere instantly as text?

Comment: You could use [OneTab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/onetab/chphlpgkkbolifaimnlloiipkdnihall) to save all open tabs, then pull the links from the text file it uses to save them within its extension folder

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Collections tools but it doesn't handle the titles :

- right-click on a tab > add all tabs to collection > start a new collection
- then click on the newly created collection or find it through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> or three dots menu > additional tools > collections
- in the collection, three dots menu > copy all

The labels may differ since my edge is in french and I translated them.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the links to a `folder` in the `favorites bar`:

[image: Folders]

When you `right-click` this folder, you can choose to `open all` links in this folder:

[image: Open all]

You can also `export` these favorite sites to other devices:

[image: Export]

After exporting the links, you can copy them as `text` or `HTML`:

[image: HTML]

If the purpose of copying the links is just to open them all at once, you can skip the last step.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.